# How to show positive definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra

For continuous functions $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, define

$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)\mathop{dx}.$$

How can I show this form is positive definite? I want to show

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2} \mathop{dx} \geq 0 $$

with equality only if $f(x) = 0$. I know how to do this by assuming $f$ is differentiable, but is it possible without knowing this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2} \mathop{dx} \geq 0 $$ should be clear from the definition of the integral.

Now assume $f$ is not identically zero. Then there is an $x_0\in [0,1]$ with $\delta:=f(x_0)>0.$ As $f$ is continuous, there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>\delta/2$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ with $|x-x_0|<\varepsilon.$ Now the integral has to be at least $\varepsilon \cdot \delta^2/4>0.$

Comment: why must the integral be at least $\epsilon \cdot \delta/2$? I thought it must be at least $(\delta/2)$^{2}$?

Comment: Correct, I'll make a correction. Doesn't change the core of the argument to be sure. Thanks for spotting this

Comment: okay. why is it $\epsilon \cdot \delta^{2}/4$ and not just $\delta^{2}/4$? because you can do $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2} \mathop{dx} \geq \int_{0}^{1}\delta^{2}/4 \mathop{dx} = \delta^{2}/4 \int_{0}^{1} \mathop{dx} = \delta^{2}/4$

Comment: You can't do that as you only know that $f(x)>\delta/2$ for those $x$ in the interval $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon) \cap [0,1].$ That interval has length at least $\varepsilon,$ however.

Comment: ok thanks it makes sense

Answer (score 3):

So, the theorem you want:

Let $g$ be a nonnegative continuous function on $[a,b]$. Suppose that there is some $x\in [a,b]$ such that $g(x) > 0$. Then $\int_a^b g(t)\,dt > 0$.

Proof: Put a box under the graph:

[image: A graph with a box under it]

The integral is at least the area of the box, which is positive. Why does a box fit? Because if we choose $\epsilon$ between $0$ and $g(x)$, there is some $\delta$ such that $g(x+y)>g(x)-\epsilon$ for $|y|<\delta$. The box runs from $x-\delta$ to $x+\delta$ horizontally, and up to $g(x)-\epsilon$ vertically.

Addendum: we didn't actually use global continuity, only continuity at the single point $x$. As such, several variations of this theorem are possible, such as the following: if $f$ is integrable and strictly positive on an interval $I$, and $f$ is continuous at at least one point of $I$, then $\int_I f > 0$.